# How to make xampp work while im using proxy internet settings?

Tags: php, apache, proxy, xampp, localhost

Well the problem is that im using my college's proxy settings to connect to the internet.Now whenever i type in localhost in the url bar(IE or chrome) it redirects me to my collge server instead of XAMPP but as soon as i change my system's intenet settings to "No connection" it starts working again.Well,interestingly this doesn't happens with mozilla where i have to explicitly give the proxy settings. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add localhost and 127.0.0.1 as exception for the proxy server in the browser's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

open "Internet Options" by typing it in the start menu, then in the "Connections" tab, click LAN Settings, and under the "Proxy server" group, make sure that the checkbox for "bypass proxy for local addresses" is on

[LAN Settings, Proxy server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvwgC.png)